# d.setDate(d.getDate()+7) returns a bunch of numbers

Tags: javascript, date, new-operator, getdate

When i run the code bellow, which parses the current date + 7 days, returns huge number on the date variable;

```
let d = new Date();
let n = d.setDate(d.getDate()+7);
let m = d.getMonth()+1;
let o = d.getFullYear();
let dateOp = n + "/" + m + "/" + o;

dateOp;

// returns "1609772260625/1/2021"
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Return_value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), `setDate` returns the millisecond difference between the date and the UNIX epoch. So, set the date first, then get the date again:

```js
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
let n = d.getDate();
let m = d.getMonth()+1;
let o = d.getFullYear();
let dateOp = n + "/" + m + "/" + o;

dateOp;
```

Comment: the date was set to ```let d = new Date();```